# Chrome Remote Debugging: "Detached from the target" error

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging

I'm remote debugging a mobile website in Chrome on my mobile device (htc one), connected via USB to my Mac. Everything works fine, except that I get an error every ~30 seconds in my desktop browser:

```
Detached from the target
Remote debugging has been terminated with reason: websocket_closed
Please re-attch to the new target.
```

If I then check the attached devices with *adb devices*, there are none. So I unplug my device, wait some seconds, reconnect it again with *adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:chrome_devtools_remote* and everthing works fine - until the same error occurs.

Does anybody know how I can pretend this error?